# Text under fixed and absolute positioned divs

Tags: css

I have something like this (just piece of design) http://jsfiddle.net/eoL458o0/1/ and I need to place text in `.content` on the top, because `anchor` is not clickable now. `#gradient` is fixed, because of background image which is also fixed and `#empty` has absolute position, because I need to have covered whole body and it must be scrollable, there is dynamically set height with jQuery.

Thanks for help.

```css
#empty {
    background-color: rgba(99,115,99,0.25);
    margin-top: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#gradient {
background: rgba(255,255,255,0);
background: -moz-radial-gradient(50% 65%, ellipse cover, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.50) 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(radial, 50% 65% 50% 65%, 0px, 50% 65% 50% 65%, 100%, color-stop(0%, rgba(255,255,255,0)), color-stop(100%, rgba(0,0,0,0.50)));
background: -webkit-radial-gradient(50% 65%, ellipse cover, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.50) 100%);
background: -o-radial-gradient(50% 65%, ellipse cover, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.50) 100%);
background: -ms-radial-gradient(50% 65%, ellipse cover, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.50) 100%);
background: radial-gradient(ellipse at 50% 65%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.50) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#000000', GradientType=1 );

position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;

}

.content {
    color: #000; 
    margin-top: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container content" role="main">
 <div class="row">
     <p class="col-md-6">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <a href="#">consectetur adipisicing</a> elit.
     </p>
    </div>
</div> <!-- /container -->
<div id="gradient"></div>
<div id="empty"></div>
```

Comment: @Paulie_D good point, I edited my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your css, just add:

```
z-index:-1;
```

to those two divs so they go to the bottom